# Counter python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nan

I read in a [data set(https://outcomestat.baltimorecity.gov/Transportation/100EBaltimoreST/k7ux-mv7u/about) with `pandas.read_csv()` with no modifying args.

- In the `stolenVehicleFlag` column there are 0, 1, and NaN.
- The nans return`False` when compared to `np.nan` or `np.NaN`.
- The column is typed `numpy.float64` so I tried typing the np.nans
  to that from the float-type that they normally are but it still
  returns `False`.
- I also tried using a `Counter` to roll them up but each nan returns its
  own count of 1.

  Any ideas on how this is happening and how to deal with it?

Comment: Also, tried math's nan object and that obj converted to np.float64 and still False.

Comment: I think you can check [missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) and if need check `NaN`s use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) function like `print (df['stolenVehicleFlag'].isnull())`.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far

Comment: @jezrael Please post your comment as an answer because the link led me to seeing in the nan documentation that np.nan == np.nan => False, which would explain why nans interpreted as numpy floats would be not equal to each other and not rolled up by the Counter but ones interpreted as strings would since they are just 'nan'. Thank you

Comment: @user85779 - glad can help. I create answer too, but I dont understand `to roll them up but each nan returns its own count of 1.` Can you explain more?

Comment: If it was rolling them up/summarizing then it would return Counter({0.0: 1500, 1.0: 22000, nan:15000}).  All the nan values would be considered the same and the Counter would one up for each one in the column I am summarizing.  Instead what I got was Counter({0.0: 1500, 1.0: 22000, nan:1, nan:1, nan:1,...,nan.1}) because nan != nan. @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting to do but may be this could help if you want to get rid of this NaN values considering "df" your dataframre use:

```
df.dropna()
```

This will help you with NaN values,
You can check for more information here : [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: I am dropping the column into a Counter object to get a count of each value including seeing how many null/nan entries there are.  With this column that Counter is resulting in thousands of separate entries in the object of nan:1 instead of rolling them up to nan:11098. All the other columns roll the nans up and give a count of the total.